# "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'UpdateHost_Python'"

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to run a python code in code inline an AWS Lambda function.

I am not zipping any file just pasting the below code in the Lambda function.

And I am getting this error:

> errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'UpdateHost_Python'

```
import psycopg2

def lambda_handler(event,context):

    conn_string = "dbname='myfirstdb' port='5432' user='db28' password='@@@@@@' host='@@@@@.ck0zbnniqteb.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com'"

    conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("select * from unnmesh")
    conn.commit()
    cursor.close()
    print("working")
```

Comment: When I run that, I get the message `Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'psycopg2'`. How are you providing the `psycopg2` library to the function?

Comment: I have just written the import line. I am not sure how to do that? Could you please suggest

Answer (score 0):

For non-standard Python libraries (like `psycopg2`), you will need to create a **Deployment Package**.

This involves creating a Zip file with the libraries, then uploading the Zip file to Lambda.

See: [AWS Lambda Deployment Package in Python - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html)

For a worked-through example, see also: [Tutorial: Using AWS Lambda with Amazon S3 - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html) (I know you're not using Amazon S3, but the tutorial gives an example of building a package with dependencies.)